# Получить те сущности, у которых дочерняя связь имеет все перечисленные значения? (TypeOrm, SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, typeorm

Как получить те сущности, у которых дочерняя связь имеет **все** перечисленные значения?

В данные момент возвращаются те, у которых дочерняя связь имеют **любое** из перечисленных значений.

```
  const qb = this.postRepository.createQueryBuilder('p');
  qb.leftJoin('p.tags', 'tags');
```

Такие поиски ищут одно любое совпадение:

1:

```
  qb.where(`tags.content ILIKE ANY(ARRAY[:...tags])`, {tags: tags});
```

2:

```
  qb.where(`tags.content IN (:...tags)`, {tags: tags});
```

`ALL` вместо `ANY` тоже не дает результат.

Типизация сущностей такая:

Post:

```
  @Entity()
  export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(() => Tag, (tags) => tags.post)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'tags_id' })
    tags: Tag[];
  }
```

Tag:

```
  @Entity()
  export class Tag {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    content: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => Post, (post) => post.tags, {
      orphanedRowAction: 'delete',
    })
    post: Relation<Post>;
  }
```

Comment: На уровне SQL это `SELECT entity FROM table WHERE tag IN ( {tags list} ) GROUP BY entity HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = {tags list length};`.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

`@Akina` дал ответ для `sql` в комментарии.

`Typeorm` версия ответа выглядит так:

```
qb.where(`tags.content IN (:...tags)`, { tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'] });
qb.having(`COUNT(DISTINCT tags.content) = :length`, { length: 2 });
qb.groupBy('p.id, tags.id');
```